# Compile-Time Enforcement of Semantic Rules

Tags: c++, clang, d, semantics

A compiler enforces rules of syntax. What I want is a semantic compiler, or a semantic stage on top of a normal compiler.

I'm not sure the best way to go about it. Some languages *may* have direct means, some languages may allow you to "abuse" things like templates to enforce it, lastly, Clang allows very powerful AST generation. But I'm not aware of any tools that use it to enforce arbitrary rules.

I'm looking for a powerful static, (compile-time) "context" checker.

For example: I want to ensure (with a compile time warning or error message) that the return value of a particular function has been evaluated. Pretty simple, and the helpful folks at the D forums have provided some sample code.

But what about other rules? For example, generating an error when someone calls a library function before calling a prerequisite initialization function. (*) Sure, you could spawn an exception. But shouldn't a more elegant, compile-time, solution and system already exist when the problem itself is inherently static? Or am I reduced to "bending" languages with exotic template voodoo to do what I would like?

(*) Yes, that case may require a dynamic checker. But it may not depending on the context. Like using a variable before initializing it.

I have seen some code checkers that do "best practices" scanning. Do any of them (that are free) support custom rules? And are they very invasive to the development process? Ideally, all I want is "user defined semantic rules that produce compiler errors or warnings" when I go to compile my project.

p.s. I realize in advance that some people will proclaim that "code enforcement" should be relegated to code guidelines and that you cannot force programmers to follow rules. But I'm not asking for perfection. I'm asking for the lead developer of a project to be able to enforce certain rules with a compiler, which will force others to notice when those rules are being violated.

Comment: can you give us at least an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: You should design your libraries so they can't be abused (easily). Example: Requiring a `initialization` function be called is a simple one. You put it in an a constructor. Now you can't call the method without creating the object at which point the initializer has been already run. Example: return value of a particular function has been evaluated. Turn on all your compiler warnings, the compiler will tell you if you have done something wrong.

Comment: In regard to making sure the return value is used, C++17 will likely have a `[[nodiscard]]` attribute.

Comment: Many of these sound like invariants. Which really isn't the job of a static analyzer. For example, are you going to force your users this hard dependency if they want to use your library? That would be quite silly, wouldn't it?

Comment: @user6292850 Why is "invariant checking" not part of a static analyzers' job?

Comment: You have to be careful to not fall into the halting problem.

Comment: I think for the sake of progress we should restrict discussion to "can it be done" and not "should it be done."

As for examples, I believe I already gave some. Guaranteeing return values being checked, as well as guaranteeing previous, prerequisite function calls have taken place. These can be done with template voodoo in C++, but a proper system wouldn't use an (lower level than necessary) in-language function mechanism to accomplish this. It could be AST based and separate from the code itself.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Static analyzers can always provide one of three answers: a)  that can't happen  b) that *will* happen, c)  not sure (this handles the "halting problem".

Comment: @KatasticVoyage:  Yes, you *can* implement an code enforcement tool.  It will give you one of 3 answers (see ratchfreak response) for each enforced rule, at each place in the code where the enforcement might apply.   If your code enforcement rules are difficult to check, or your code has properties that make it hard to check, you might get the "not sure" answer a lot.    How much of that you get will determine how *useful* the tool will be, and therefore whether you *should* implement such a tool.  Without specific examples of rules-to-check, its pretty hard to predict how this will turn out.

Comment: *A compiler enforces [only] rules of syntax.* Simply not true, unless we **call** every rule that a compiler enforces a rule of syntax. (The way we can call a tail a leg, and then assert that a dog has five legs).

Comment: How is this post off-topic? I asked very specifically: "what kind of tool can be used to implement user-defined semantic rules in source code?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a customizable program analysis tool.

My understanding is that Clang can do that, and is sort of designed to make this relatively easy.  You can customize Clang to implement arbitrary predicates on your code; you write these customizations all in C++ AFAIK.  Clang also acts as a compiler so you could presumably integrate these into a single Clang image.

My understanding that you can also do this with GCC, but it was not designed for this purpose so doing this is generally a lot harder in practice.  [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) is supposed to make this easier.  IMHO it is just as complicated as GCC so I don't see how this helps much.  YMMV.

A third approach is to use a tool that is designed specifically to support such customization.  Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) and its [C++ front end](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html) are this kind of tool. You can use it to define semantic constraints, using a combination of [source-level pattern matching](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSRewriteRules.html) and arbitrary predicates coded over symbol tables values/C++ types and method-local control and data flow analysis.

Comment: Thanks for being the one poster that actually answered the question instead of nitpicking or flagging the post.

Comment: I've actually been implementing a lot of these features with D now, as well as AST processing using D-Scanner.